# Script to set end date with Flexible Budget Script

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I'm currently using the flexible budget script found here : https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/flexible-budgets.

Is there anyway to add in some line(s) of javascript that will stop the campaign once END_DATE has been reached?

Thanks.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the simplest way to do this would be to add a function, which checks dates before you do anything with budget settings. If you're on the end, then call `pause()` method ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_campaign#pause_0)). However, you need to consider one very important thing, which is your AdWords account's time zone vs script's time zone. As written in [this article](http://www.rankhammer.com/blog/1616/adwords-script-use-correct-date):

> (...) even though the AdWords account time was Central, dates generated
>   in an AdWords script are based off of the server time where the script
>   is running (...)

There's also a simple function to set proper time zone:

```
/**
 * The time will convert to whatever server/data center the script is running on. Make sure the time is set to the AW account time
 * @param {Date} date
 */
function setProperTimeZone(date) {
  return new Date(Utilities.formatDate(date, AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone(), "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
}
```